# Java - Error on use of Timer

Tags: java, swing, timer, actionlistener

So I have googled some minutes how to use the timer and found some helpfull threads here. But when I want to use the suggested code Eclipse shows me always an error.

```
int delay = 1000; //milliseconds
               ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
                   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                       label.setVisible(false);
                   }
               };
               new Timer(delay, taskPerformer).start();
```

This is my code I want to use now. Eclipse underlines the last line and when they suggest to "remove arguments to match 'Timer()' ". Further it underlines start() and want it to be casted. :S

Can someone help me pls? I've installed the last Java version^^

Thx a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

take a look at your imports.  Eclipse has auto imported `java.util.Timer`.  Change that to `javax.swing.Timer` and you should be on your way.

Answer (score 4):

Import `javax.swing.Timer` not `java.util.Timer`.

Swing `Timer` has a constructor [Timer(int , java.awt.event.ActionListener)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html#Timer%28int,java.awt.event.ActionListener%29).

Answer (score 3):

your import is wrong there correct that

change

```
java.util.Timer
```

to

```
javax.swing.Timer
```